# svchost.exe prevents android emulator to run

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

Every time i close android emulator, it will not run again and i should go to 
**Task Manager/Right click emulator/ Go to detail/ Right click Emulator process** and after selecting **Analyse wait chain** i see android emulator is waiting because of **svchost.exe**. so i click th button **End process** to end that **svchost** process. then the emulator starts.. but the problem is that, after that my sound card stop working and wireless networks will stop showing in network list!!
Anybody knows what is the problem with **AVD**?

Answer (score 0):

You have to find the problematic service under that `svchost.exe` process to troubleshoot what's really causing the crash.

Using command line:

Your can simply enter

```
tasklist /svc /fi "IMAGENAME eq svchost.exe
```

The lookup the related services, if they are configured correctly or starting correctly.

You may need to repair service permissions or restoring important windows services in start up.